# Некоторые ошибки в google webmasters (в заблокированные ресурсах)

Tags: индексация

Помогите найти причину ошибок в Google webmasters http://joxi.ru/DrlbVNBF4BjNk2

Сообщает о заблокированных ресурсах, хотя в роботсе не заблокирован доступ к индексации к этим страницам. Вот роботс:

```
User-agent: *

Allow: /*/*.js
Allow: /*/*.css
Allow: /wp-*.png
Disallow: /coupon-categories/*
Disallow: /wp-admin/*
Disallow: /coupons/*
Disallow: /coupon-tags/*
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-register.php
Disallow: /xmlrpc.php
Disallow: /wp-admin
Disallow: /wp-comments
Disallow: /archive
Disallow: /wp-trackback
Disallow: */trackback/
Disallow: */feed
Disallow: /tag/
Sitemap: http://ali-coupons.net/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваших запретах ничего особенного нет, в основном логотип который отображается и динамические библиотеки *js, которые особой музыки не играют, кроме как красивого отображения контента со всплывающими окнами, слайдерами, движущими аккордеонами и тому подобное.

Всё что считается заблокированным наверняка не влияет на индексацию, потому что ваш сайт рабочий и есть в поиске Гугл\Яндекс.

Comment: ну ок, спасибо!!